# C++ accessing vector

Tags: c++, vector, std

I have `std::vector` which contains my own class and I have to access its functions and voids.

```
class A
{
private: 
     int var;
     vector<string> vec;

public:
     void setVar(int i) { var = i; }
     void setVec(vector<string> a) { vec = a; }
};
```

I have also return functions but I didn't bother to type them. And I have included all necessary files.

```
int main()
{
    vector<A> vec;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        A tmp;
        tmp.setVar(i);
        vec.push_back(tmp);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        vector<string> tmp;
        tmp.push_back("1");
        tmp.push_back("2");
        tmp.push_back("3");
        vec.at(i).setVec(tmp);  //Works sometimes or causes error std::out_of_range
        vec[i].setVec(tmp);     //Crashes the whole programm
    }
}
```

So how do I set those variables since the `vector` is initialized?

I am using g++ and this is not actual code because my actual code is messy.

```
Error for vec.at(i).setVec(tmp);
Error is:  terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check
```

Comment: This code won't compile for me.  Are you sure that the setup of `tmp` here is your actual code?  When I fix that to do something valid to set up 3 `string`s in the `vector`, this code runs fine.

Comment: With the updated code, I don't see any reason that this should fail. Does the code that you have written here crash for you?

Answer (score 2):

Which compiler are you using ? I'm actually very surprised that `std::vector<std::string> tmp("1","2","3");` even compiles !

To be honest I have no idea what it calls, but I bet that it doesn't do what you expect, which I believe is  :

```
std::vector<std::string> tmp;
tmp.push_back("1");
tmp.push_back("2");
tmp.push_back("3");
```

For the record, [boost.assign](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html#list_of) and [C++0x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Initializer_lists) provides the kind of container initialization you were trying to achieve.

Comment: I believe this is made up code. If he typed `vector<string> tmp("1", "2");` it would have compiled but it doesn't do what is expected.

Comment: That was not my actual code. I made that to clarify the meaning. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted still won't compile (no `tmp` declared in the first loop), so let me explain in general what happens.

There are two kinds errors you mentioned:

```
vec.at(i).setVec(tmp);  //Works sometimes or causes error std::out_of_range
```

The function `at` tries to be safe - it first checks the length of the vector, then returns the element of the given index, or throws `std::out_of_range` if the vector doesn't contain the element of such index.

The second case:

```
vec[i].setVec(tmp);     //Crashes the whole programm
```

Operator `[]` behaves much like the `at()` function for vectors, but it not "safe" as it does not do any bounds-checking. Therefore, if you try to access 4-th element of a 3-element, you just access some random place in your memory (could be another, unrelated variable, for example, could be anything else). If you're lucky, your program will crash after that. If you're unlucky, you'll have memory corruption issues and very strange bugs, hard to find.

**The solution to your problem is:**

a) Replace `vec[i]` with `vec.at(i)` - work the same (well, *a tiny bit* slower, but you won't feel that) and you're secure.

b) Then: Look at all the places when you actually do this vector lookup and in every place stop for a second and consider: "how big is this vector at this moment? am I sure that the element of this index exists?".

You're likely to find your bug quickly this way.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code in VS2010 and was not able to reproduce the problem you described. Surely, passing vector by value is not a good idea, it should be a reference to a constant, but it cannot cause such error. Taking the fact that 'std::out_of_range' is raised, the most likely cause is that there is no element with such index in your vector. For testing, you can check if `i < vec.size()` before accessing `vec[i]` (or `vec.at(i)`)

Answer (score 0):

I found problem. It was in function which handled the size of the vector. Apparently vector was empty. Dumb mistake. Thank you all for answers.