# Find object throwing std::out_of_range

Tags: c++, debugging, exception, stl

A program of mine throws a `std::out_of_range`. I know the reason for that, I'm accessing a vector with index `-1` somewhere. What I don't know is the name of the vector (variable name) and location in the code. The error message produced by my program looks like this:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check
zsh: abort (core dumped)  ./main.x config.cfg
```

whereas the error message produced by the code of some other guy (he uses `g++` too) and posted in the question [C++ accessing vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247079/c-accessing-vector) looks like this:

```
Error for vec.at(i).setVec(tmp);
Error is:  terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check
```

I.e. he is told the name of the variable. My question is:

Is there any way to tell `g++`/`gcc` to give me the extended info? Maybe even include line numbers (don't know whether that's possible but hey, a guy can dream ;) ).
Just for funsies I ran my program in `gdb` with the `catch thrown` option (I might add, I have near zero experience in using an actual debugger) which didn't tell me anything new either, in fact, it didn't tell me that the error was due to a `std::out_of_range` exception.

Btw, my compiler flags (for debug) are:

```
CFLAGS = --exceptions -I$(ROOTSYS)/include --std=c++11 -Wall -g -O0 -fno-inline -fno-eliminate-unused-debug-types
```

Comment: After running `gdb` with `catch throw`, when the exception is caught, type `where`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Perfect! So now I got line numbers from `gdb`, any chance to get the second error message (i.e. name without a debugger)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After hitting the breakpoint enter `bt` (backtrace) command in the gdb shell. This will print the stack trace (a sequence of function calls leading to the error).

To get the variable name you can now use `up` command to navigate upwards in the stack and see what variables where used in each of those functions.

Comment: This works as expected, after moving to the top of the stack (i.e. multiple `up` commands) the line with the faulty code is printed.

Answer (score 4):

Put a breakpoint on `std::out_of_range::out_of_range`. An exception object, like all C++ objects, starts its life after its constructor exits.

[EDIT]
Comment made it clear: the problem the string produced by `std::out_of_range::what()`. That's implementation-defined. Obviously in your case it's composed from `__FUNCTION__`, a GCC macro which names the current (i.e. throwing) function. But such a function only knows `this`, i.e. the pointer to the current object and not its name. In the other case, the objects name is retrieved via some other method, not `std::out_of_range::what()`.

Comment: I assume you mean that I execute `break std::out_of_range::out_of_range` in `gdb` prior to executing the application (i.e. command `run`). Only doing this has the same effect as `catch throw`, thus issuing `where` after the breakpoint has been reached (as suggested by @DavidSchwartz) shows the line number. However, similar to his solution this involves using a debugger, right? That is to say the second error message can't be achieved using this method.

Comment: I assume there is no easy way to add the functionality of printing the objects name?

Comment: @elemakil: No, that's the point. The function which throws _does_ know the `this` pointer to the object, and its own function name, but not the object name. (Leaving aside the philosophical question what _the_ object name is anyway - that usually depends on how deep you're in the callstack).

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept @Basilevs answer as he gave an easy way for finding line number and object name using `gdb`, however, your answer has been very helpful on the general context.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid hitting a break point at every exception thrown and stop only at`std::out_of_range` use this command in `gdb`:

```
catch throw std::out_of_range
```

Then run the commad `bt` or `where` when the breack point is hit to see where in the code the exception was thrown